# why is this sentence in interrogative form?

Tags: grammar

> Can you think of a real world example or context that would it make sense for x and y to represent, and produce such a graph?
>   If not, can you change the graph and make it simpler to fit with a scenario you can imagine?

Why does "would" precede "it" instead of just following it?

The text is from Microsoft Math (limit example 1).

Comment: The "would it" issue is an error.

Comment: It's a mistake. Sooo many of them out there. It's a pretty poorly worded question over all. I would rewrite it as "...context in which it would make sense for x and y to represent this [or whatever preceeded the question] and produce such a graph?

Comment: @medica. Yes: a better overall rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

It is an error that has not been picked up in proofreading.

Comment: Hello, chasly. True, but the question is not suitable for ELU (and thus is better not graced with an 'answer'). Which is doubtless why someone has downvoted (I'm not downvoting correct but inappropriate answers for people with fewer than 1000 rep points).

Comment: Right @Edwin-ashworth. Sorry chasly . I posted it here mistakenly on my small-screen phone, as I meant to post it on ELL. I'll flag it to be transferred to ELL.

Comment: @JasonStack No need, now you've got the explanation.

Comment: @JasonStack Even on ELL the answer is the same, it's just an error. No need to have it transferred.